# Do I get any benefit if I use python-qt with pycharm?

Tags: python, pyside, pycharm

Can I use python-qt with pycharm or is it already shipped or built into pycharm?

If I use python-qt with pyside when developing in pycharm, will I get any benefit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm itself does not use either Qt or python-qt, and does not ship with either of those. Developing your own projects using python-qt in PyCharm might possible; however, python-qt is designed to be embedded into C++ applications, and PyCharm does not include any C++ support.